# Events website with email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, events, web

Apologies for a somewhat basic request but our boss wants to add an events system to our website which subsequently alerts subscribers by email to any new events in their chosen category, such as live music.

The site we're currently using runs Wordpress but I don't mind using something else if it does what we need it to do. We use an events plugin called EventOn so ideally I'd like to marry the notification system to this if at all possible. But again, I'm not averse to leaving Wordpress (for the events system at least) if we can manage to do what our MD is after.

I've looked on ProgrammeableWeb but couldn't find what we're looking for.

So if anyone has any pointers to an online tutorial or a plugin we could use then I'd be very grateful.

Or even just what I should look for when searching through the many php tutorials.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is a poor fit because you're recommending that we advise of libraries or tools to complete your task. Instead, this is a Q&A programming site. You have code that isn't functioning as intended, we review the code to help complete the task at hand. Please revise your question to include the code you're attempting to use that isn't working.

Comment: Fair point - it probably isn't the first place to start looking for  a fairly open question like that. Where would you recommend I start? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That events plugin is using custom posts for events called `ajde_events` (judging from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGGLl4QNZpI)) which means that you can easily fire an action every time an event is created like this:

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'tell_others');
   function tell_others( $post_id ) {

       // Making sure this runs only when an event post type is created
       $slug = 'ajde_events';
       if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
          return;
       }

       // After this you can email your subscribers or run a function.
       // It's recommended you use another service for sending bulk emails.

       // Simple email sender

       $event_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
       $event_url = get_permalink( $post_id );

       $to = 'myemail@email.com';
       $subject = $event_title;
       $content = 'Yo! the new event url is: <a href="'.$event_url.'">'.$event_title .'</a>.';

       $status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
}
```

Comment: Thnx. accept if this is what you wanted.